# Flink K8s operator ignores taskmanager.host setting

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I'm deploying a job via the Flink K8s Operator with these settings in
the FlinkDeployment resource:

```
spec:
flinkConfiguration:
taskmanager.host: 0.0.0.0 <-- ignored / not applied
```

When I look into the `flink-conf.yaml` in the TM the setting is not there. Is
there any reason why `taskmanager.host` gets ignored? Is that a bug or
something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the operator discovers it via service discovery automatically that's why it is unnecessary to specify it manually.

When you deploy Flink with the operator, it creates a headless service for the taskmanagers, which serves as a way for the taskmanagers to discover each other. The operator also sets the j`obmanager.rpc.address` configuration to the hostname of the jobmanager, allowing the taskmanagers to connect to the jobmanager.

There are some scenarios in which the [`taskmanager.host`](http://taskmanager.host) is still used, like using standalone mode or custom service discovery mechanism

If [`taskmanager.host`](http://taskmanager.host) is needed to be set, you can go and set the `TASK\_MANAGER\_HOST` environment variable for the task manager pods.

This environment variable will override the default behavior of the operator and force the taskmanagers to use the specified host.